# Change subscription of Angular2 Async Pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a case where I'm using an async pipe in a angular2 component and passing an observable to it. That works fine.

What I want is later, while the component is still 'alive', i.e.: OnDestroy has not been called (hence async pipe is subscribed), to unsubscribe from that observable and subscribe to another.

How can I achieve this ?

Here's some pseudo code to expose this case :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pack',
  template: `
    <wolf *ngFor="let wolf of pack | async">
      ...
    </wolf>
  `
})
export class PackComponent implements DoCheck {

    pack;

    constructor(){
      this.pack = Observable.of(northwesthernWolves: Wolf[])
    }

    onDoCheck() {
      if(some condition) {
        this.pack = Observable.of(redWolves: Wolf[])
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that the framework has been released, it is safe to assume that it already takes care of this. And actually, [it is so](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L94-L97):

```
...
if (obj !== this._obj) {
  this._dispose();
  return this.transform(obj);
}
...
```

When new observable is assigned to class property, the old one is unsubscribed automatically by `async` pipe.

The opposite behaviour would lead to memory leaks and could be considered a bug.

Comment: This does not answer. I need to change the async subscription inside the component class. These methods are declared and running inside the async pipe class.

Comment: The point of the answer is that you don't need to care about this, the framework does this for you when you do `this.pack = Observable.of(redWolves: Wolf[])` . What did make you think that you need to unsubscribe it manually? Do you have related problems with the code you've posted?

Comment: When I do that I get the browser blocked. I have a case where I need to change the subscription in the component class. I'll detail : My initial subscription is of an SSE event but I also run a callback on a promise (both to server). While the stream of SSEvents works fine, I want to reset the pipe subscription to the return of promise (an array) once the callback is invoked. I believe I might have to unsubscribe to do that, but am not sure.

Comment: As the answer explains, you don't need to do that manually, when new observable is assigned to class property, the old one is unsubscribed automatically by async pipe. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: But async pipe unsubscribes when OnDestroy is invoked, to prevent memory leak. Why do you say unsubscribe method is called on variable re-assignment?

Comment: Observable `unsubscribe` (internal `_dispose` method in pipe) is called in two places, on destroy and on source replacement. The snippet in the answer shows where replacement detection happens. I guess you can try to wrap `this.pack = Observable.of(redWolves: Wolf[])` with `setTimeout` to make sure that the changes are detected.

Comment: I don't get it... I tried and re-tried that and always get stuck. But you're right and sorry for not getting there right away, but the async pipe has given me some tough challenges to work on. I think I might be running into zone delegation problems but am not sure, anyway, that's another question... thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I guess that recreating the problem as a plunker/fiddle would help in detecting the issue.

Comment: can you make a minor edit to the question so I can change my vote please (stackoverflow policy) ?